# Search for a specific term via jQuery AJAX and keyup event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to build a coupon system into my website and I'm wanting to use jQuery AJAX for this.

So how I'm trying to do it...

I have an array in **coupon.php** with this data in it:

```
Array
(
    [admins] => 50
    [helpers] => 20
)
```

**admins** is the coupon and **50** is the sale the user will get. The user presented with the html form will need to enter the coupon name of course.

**This is how my jQuery looks like:**

```
$(function() {
    var ilength = 3;

    var price_class = document.getElementsByClassName('price_no');
    var price_no = parseFloat(price_float[0].innerHTML);

    $('#coupon_entry').keyup(function() {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= ilength)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'coupon.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'coupon': value},
                dataType: 'html',

                success: function(result) {
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        $('.price_no').text(result / 100 * price_no);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**And this is how** `.price_no` **looks like in HTML:**

```
<span class="price">Total: <strong><span class="price_no">28.9</span> USD</strong></span>
```

**And this is how I process the whole thing in PHP:**

```
$coupon_post     = $_POST['coupon'];
$coupons_str_ary = explode(';', $config['mp_coupons']);
$coupons_array   = array();

foreach ($coupons_str_ary as $coupon)
{
    $coupon_percentage = substr(strrchr($coupon, '='), 1);  
    $coupon_name = $market->reverse_strrchr($coupon, '=', 0);

    $coupons_array[$coupon_name] = $coupon_percentage;
}

unset($coupons_array[0]);
echo (array_key_exists($coupon_post, $coupons_array)) ? (float) $coupons_array[$coupon_post] : 0;
?>
```

This PHP script has that array I posted above, and then I use the user's input to call the key of the array and then the return message (`echo`) is used to get the new sale price if the coupon is used.

---

## The issue

Nothing I described above is working -- the number is not changing at all.

P.S: I also used the jQuery `text()` method. but `.price_no` would always become/return `NaN`, then I switched to classic Javascript to grab the class name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var price_class = document.getElementsByClassName('price_no');
var price_no = parseFloat(price_float[0].innerHTML); //error is here
```

I think you have to change price_float[0] to price_class[0]

Comment: I feel blind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change your code do this

```
var price_class = document.getElementsByClassName('price_no');
 //variable name is price_class not price_float
var price_no = parseFloat(price_class[0].innerHTML);
```